# Android: Delaying messages possible via spinners

Tags: android, spinner, delay

The user chooses among the 4 choices on how long the delay is in a spinner (e.g, 15, 30, 60 seconds or no delay) then when he clicks on the send button the delay will take effect before the message really sends then when it sends there'll be a toast to notify the user that his message is sent.

The question is, how do I implement the delay on the spinner? Is it going to be in OnitemSelected? then delay it there? or whatsoever?

Here's the code:

```
public class KAHTextApp extends Activity {
    Button btnRecipient;
    Button btnSend;
    EditText editTextRecipient;
    EditText editTextNewMessage;
    Spinner spinnerTimeDelay;

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.compose_message);

        btnRecipient = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_recipient_picker);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        editTextRecipient = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_recipient);
        editTextNewMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_new_message);
        spinnerTimeDelay = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_delay);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.delay_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerTimeDelay.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerTimeDelay.setOnItemSelectedListener(new TimeDelay());

        btnRecipient.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (reqCode) {
            case (CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT):

                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor contactsCursor = managedQuery(contactData,
                            null, null, null, null);
                    if (contactsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                        String name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String hasPhoneNumber = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                        sb.append(name);
                        if (Integer.parseInt(hasPhoneNumber) > 0) {
                            Uri myPhoneUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, id);
                            Cursor phoneCursor = managedQuery(
                                    myPhoneUri, null, null, null, null);
                            for (phoneCursor.moveToFirst(); !phoneCursor.isAfterLast(); phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                                String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                                sb.append(phoneNumber);
                            }
                        } else {
                            sb.append("This contact doesn't have a phone number");
                        }
                        editTextRecipient.setText(sb.toString());
                    }
                }
                break;
            }

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = editTextRecipient.getText().toString();
                String message = editTextNewMessage.getText().toString(); 

                if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)   
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                            "Message sent!", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    /*sendSMS(phoneNo, message);  */              
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });        
    }
```

and here's the code for the spinner:

```
public class TimeDelay implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The delay is " +
              parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
          // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the timer's (Handlers) for delay, means write the code for sending and toast message in that and call that function depending on the delay time ( selected from spinner), just select a value from the spinner. by using this value call the function (delay).

```
handler = new Handler(); 
handler.postDelayed(checkFunction(), n*1000);  // 1000 means 1 second
                                               // n is value selected from spinner.
```

this is the function

```
private Runnable checkFunction(){ 
    tt = new TimerTask() {            
      public void run() { 
          handler.postDelayed(checkFunction(),1000);
              //// write code depending on your requirement..
      }
  };          
    return tt;
}
```

spinner

```
 ArrayAdapter<MyFont> fontArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyFont>(this, 
                                        R.layout.spinner_layout, fontArray);
    fontArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.dropdown_spinner);
    font_spinner.setAdapter(fontArrayAdapter);
    font_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            MyFont f = fontArray[pos];
            String selected_font = f.getValue();
            System.out.println("selected one is "+selected_font);
            int item = pos;
            System.out.println("selected one is "+item);
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have two classes for this, one is the main and the other one is the time delay where the onitemselected of spinner is located, where should i put the handler? Sorry I'm only new here in android.

Comment: Its for the spinner. Just copied it from the developer's site.

Comment: Ok I've deleted the other class, help me on how to set the delays please

Comment: if it is possible, come to gmail rajareddy511@gmail.com

Comment: i saw your coding i don't know about the contact picker, what i am telling is, after user select a time for delay you can use that value in the handle and the use the function for sending the information in that function with handler. it will be sending the information depending on time.